# conditional css in create-react-app

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app

I have default css file and separate css file that should be applied (to owerride default) only when certain conditions are met.

I am using create-react-app wit default `import 'file.css'` syntax.

What is the best way forward to decide whether to load or not load particular css file dynamically?

Comment: You can use `require('file.css')` or `import('file.css')` syntax instead -- that will allow you to use it inside of a conditional.

Comment: import('file.css') does not work, while require does.add it as an answer so I can accept. and thanks

Comment: You might need [babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/) for the `import()` syntax. Webpack 2 already supports it out of the box, but Babel needs to be able to parse it. Do note, however, that `import()` is asynchronous and `require` is not.

Answer (score 48):

The `require` method only worked in development (as all the CSS is bundled upon build), and the `import` method did not work at all (using CRA version 3.3).

In our case, we have multiple themes, which cannot be bundled - so we solved this using `React.lazy` and `React.Suspense`.

We have the `ThemeSelector`, which loads the correct css conditionally.

```
import React from 'react';

/**
 * The theme components only imports it's theme CSS-file. These components are lazy
 * loaded, to enable "code splitting" (in order to avoid the themes being bundled together)
 */
const Theme1 = React.lazy(() => import('./Theme1'));
const Theme2 = React.lazy(() => import('./Theme2'));

const ThemeSelector: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    {/* Conditionally render theme, based on the current client context */}
    <React.Suspense fallback={() => null}>
      {shouldRenderTheme1 && <Theme1 />}
      {shouldRenderTheme2 && <Theme2 />}
    </React.Suspense>
    {/* Render children immediately! */}
    {children}
  </>
);

export default ThemeSelector;
```

The `Theme` component's only job, is to import the correct css file:

```
import * as React from 'react';

//  Only important line - as this component should be lazy-loaded,
//    to enable code - splitting for this CSS.
import 'theme1.css';

const Theme1: React.FC = () => <></>;

export default Theme1;
```

The `ThemeSelector` should wrap the `App` component, in the `src/index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ThemeSelector from 'themes/ThemeSelector';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeSelector>
    <App />
  </ThemeSelector>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

As I understand, this forces each `Theme` to be split into separate bundles (effectively also splitting CSS).

---

As mentioned in the comments, this solution does not present an easy way of switching themes runtime. This solution focuses on splitting themes into separate bundles.

If you already got themes split into separate CSS files, and you want to swap themes runtime, you might want to look at a solution using `ReactHelmet` ([illustrated by @Alexander Ladonin's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58539443/1980235))

Comment: We must pass some JSX to the `fallback` prop (at least for React 16.12), not a function. Something like `null` or `<div />` (but of course, something more useful in that context.

Great example!

Comment: Once loaded, there doesn't seem to be a way to unload packaged CSS, is there?  In other words I cannot create a switch that flips between light/dark themes without a full page reload.

Comment: I am not quite sure this is a solution. It ONLY works on initial load. There is not way to change themes after initial render with this method.
This is because once the "Suspense" is loaded, it CANNOT BE MODIFIED except by using context hook (and the result is not stable, believe me i tried).
Another alternative is to force a reload when theme is changed

Comment: This is definitely the best solution I have found, thank you sir

Comment: This works only on mount, the right answer is using webpack feature `lazyStyleTag`, you can also combine it with context to make a theme provider that toggles the theme by boundling and unboundling 2 css files

Answer (score 11):

You can use `require('file.css')` syntax instead. This will allow you to put it inside of a conditional.

e.g.

```
if(someCondition) {
    require('file.css');
}
```

Comment: hmm. looks like it works only in dev mode - after deploying tot he server seems like css is loaded anyway, even if particular code block is never executed. Probably css assembly happens before page loading after all :/

Comment: @MartinsUntals Yeah...if you're using ExtractTextPlugin that's what happens. You can use CSS modules and target your specific components so that it doesn't matter if the CSS is on every page or not, or you can [take a look at this](https://github.com/faceyspacey/extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin) -- I haven't tried it yet but it might be closer to what you want.

Comment: @MartinsUntals So r u able to find the solution of the dynamic CSS at deploying/production level?

Comment: I did use react html injecting tactics. Not good enough in longer term

Comment: @MartinsUntals can u please explain to me more about this tactic?

Comment: StyleInjection = props =>
    <div>
      <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 

        /*override colors GREEN*/
        header { background: #78be20; }
        .button { background: #78be20;}
        .button:hover { background: #6EAD1E; }
      `}} />
    </div>

Comment: and then render the component conditionally

Comment: @MartinsUntals I've found that using import('file.css') versus require('file.css') works in both dev mode and after the application is built.  I am using the latest version of create app.  I realize import may not worked in create-react-app during the time you post this question, but it does now.

Comment: import does not work conditionally, under import statement

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue in the end @PCalouche? in case you solved using `import` could you post a snippet of the solution? thanks!

Comment: @user3665949 in my App.js component I have this in my render method:
render() {
    const pathname = this.props.location.pathname;
    if (pathname.startsWith('/app1') || pathname === '/') {
      import('./app1/App1.scss');
    } else if (pathname.startsWith('/app2')) {
      import('./app2/App2.scss');
    }
    return (// return whatever you need to)
}

Comment: Thank you very much @PCalouche! Placing the login within a React component did the trick! I originally placed the "if" as first thing in the index.js, before the <App /> main component of my React app, and it didn't work. But like this it's a different story! thanks again!

Comment: Thank you! I have been avoiding wrestling with webpack when I felt like a simple solution had to exist! My brain is now cool again from over processing this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use [React Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet). It adds links, meta tags etc into *document header* dynamically.
Add it into any render method.

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import ReactHelmet from 'react-helmet';

class Example extends Component{
    render(
        <ReactHelmet link={
            [{"rel": "stylesheet", type:"text/css", "href": "/style.css"}]
        }/>);
    }
}
```

You can rewrite it on next `<ReactHelmet/>` rendering.

Answer (score 2):

If you are here you most likely are trying to condition a CSS or SCSS import, probably to make some light/dark mode theme or something. The accepted answer works just on mount, after the second css is loaded they are both loaded and you dont have a way to unload them, or actually you have, keep reading...

The use of React lazy and suspense is awesome but in this case we need to help our selves from webpack, because is actually the guy that bundles stuff and can also unbundle stuff, which is what you need, a toggle of css imports basically

Adding webpack [lazyStyleTag](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#lazystyletag)

Go to your webpack config file and add the following rules

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        // Probly you already have this rule, add this line
        exclude: /\.lazy\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      // And add this rule
      {
        test: /\.lazy\.css$/i,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader", options: { injectType: "lazyStyleTag" } },
          "css-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Now take your `CSS` files and change their name to the `lazy` named convention

You probably have this

```
styles.css 
// or
styles.min.css
```

Now will be this:

```
styles.lazy.css
```

Then create your React theme Provider in a simple React context, this context will wrap your App so it will load the conditioned CSS everytime the context state changes. This context state is going to be availabe anywhere inside your app as well as the setter via a custom hook we will export from the same file, check this out:

```
import React, {
    useEffect, createContext, useState, useContext,
} from 'react';
import { Nullable } from 'types';

// Import both files here like this:

// Import of CSS file number 1
import LightMode from './theme/styles.lazy.css';
// Import of CSS file number 2
import DarkMode from './theme/styles.lazy.css';

interface IContext {
    theme: Nullable<string>
    toggleTheme: () => void
}

const Context = createContext<IContext>({
    theme: null,
    toggleTheme: () => { },
});

// Your Provider component that returns the Context.Provider
// Let's also play with the sessionStorage, so this state doesn't
// brake with browser refresh or logouts
const ThemeProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    // Im initialazing here the state with any existing value in the 
    //sessionStorage, or not...
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Nullable<string>>(sessionStorage.getItem('themeMode') || 'dark');

    // this setter Fn we can pass down to anywhere
    const toggleTheme = () => {
        const newThemeValue = theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark';
        setTheme(newThemeValue);
        sessionStorage.setItem('themeMode', newThemeValue);
    };

    // Now the magic, this lazy css files you can use or unuse
    // This is exactly what you need, import the CSS but also unimport
    // the one you had imported before. An actual toggle of import in a 
    // dynamic way.. brought to you by webpack
    useEffect(() => {
        if (theme === 'light') {
            DarkMode.unuse();
            LightMode.use();
        } else if (theme == 'dark') {
            LightMode.unuse();
            DarkMode.use();
        }
    }, [theme]);


    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    );
};

export default ThemeProvider;
// This useTheme hook will give you the context anywhere to set the state of // theme and this will toggle the styles imported
export const useTheme = () => useContext(Context);
```

Remember to put this state on the sessionStorage like in this example so your user has the state available every time it comes back or refreshes the page

Don't forget to wrap the friking App with the Provider:

```
import ThemeProvider from './ThemeProvider'

const App = () => {

   return (
      <ThemeProvider>
        <App />
      </ThemeProvider>

   )
}
```

Now just toggle the CSS imports of your application using your cool `useTheme` hook

```
import { useTheme } from './yourContextFile';


// inside your component
const AnyComponentDownTheTree = () => {

   const { theme, toggleTheme } = useTheme()

   // use the toggleTheme function to toggle and the theme actual value 
   // for your components, you might need disable something or set active a 
   // switch, etc, etc 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution that I found that works in production is to use vercel's styled-jsx. First, install styled-jsx:

```
npm install --save styled-jsx
```

Or if you use Yarn:

```
yarn add styled-jsx
```

Now create strings from your css file, so for instance:

```
const style1 = `
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
`
const style2 = `
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
`
```

And then in your React Component, you can do something like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className='my-component'>
      <style jsx>
        {
          conditionA ? style1: style2
        }
      </style>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Simply add `<style jsx>{your_css_string}</style>` to the component which you wish to add styling to and you can then to implement conditions just use different strings to import different css styling.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding a sibling `div` that renders conditionally, and then utilizing the [css selector "+"](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.php) to target the conditional content. Here is an example:

```
# Layout.js

import React, { useState } from "react"
import "./main.css"

function Layout() {
  const [condition, setCondition] = useState(false);

  const toggleCondition = () => setCondition(!condition);

  return (
    <div>
      {condition && <div id="condition-is-true"></div>}
      <div className="content">
         <button onClick={toggleCondition}>Click me</button>
         <div id="conditionally-style-me">This is the content</div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

```
# main.css

#condition-is-true + .content #conditionally-style-me {
   color: red;
}

.content #conditionally-style-me {
   color: black;
}
```

Now the color of the text will be black by default, but will update to red only when the `condition === true`.  It's a bit hacky but works for my simple application.

Answer (score 0):

I tested some alternatives available in some tutorials and the best for me was to use only classes in css.

One of the problems I encountered when using

**require**: did not override on some occasions

**import**: delay generated to load css

The best way for me was to actually put a class switch

```
.default-sidebar {
    --side-text-icon:rgba(255,255,255,.9) !important;
    --side-text-section: rgb(255,255,255,.8) !important;
    --side-separator-section:#ff944d !important;
}

.dark-sidebar {
    --side-text-icon:rgba(255,255,255,.9) !important;
    --side-text-section: rgb(255,255,255,.8) !important;
    --side-separator-section:#262626 !important;
}
```

'

```
<div className={`root-sidebar ${condition?'default-sidebar':'dark-sidebar'}`}></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Other solution does not work for me. After one day of the search, I obtain bellow solution. In my issue, I have two CSS files for RTL or LTR like `app.rtl.css` or `app.ltr.css`

Create a functional component `Style` like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Style(props) {
  const [stylePath, setStylePath] = useState(props.path);

  return (
    <div>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={stylePath} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then you can call it, for example in `App.js`:

```
function App() {
...
return (    
  <Style path={`/css/app.${direction}.css`} />
)}
```

`direction` param contains `rtl` or `ltr` and determine which file should be loaded.