# How to conditionally import a SCSS stylesheet in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, import, sass, next.js

I'm trying to load a stylesheet depending on the environment, in `_app.js`:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ) {
  import '../styles/globals-production.scss'
} else {
  import '../styles/globals-staging.scss'
}
```

But getting this error in the console: `Syntax error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`

Any ideas on how I can do this with Next.js?

Comment: Can you explain why you need two stylesheets for two different environments in the first place? It's possible to import different stylesheets depending on the environment (using the CommonJS `require` syntax would work for instance, customizing webpack is another option) but there may be a better, simpler, alternative.

Comment: There already is an answer to a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835825/conditional-css-in-create-react-app#answer-46836014 But very correctly asked by @Jelefra, Why do you need this...?

Comment: Are you looking to support themes? Like dark, light themes?

Comment: Would also like such a feature. I am building a framework, where the user should be able to select what they want. If they don't want buttons, they don't need the button scss in the styling, hence if button false, don't import button.scss

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted to import rtl bootstrap so I added a selector to toggle the import.
You will need a way to add a custom attribute to the html tag.

If you are using Next I recommend nextjs custom document: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Then in your style.scss wrap the import with the custom attribute selector, ex:

```
[dir='rtl'] {
  @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The javascript import statement must appear at top level, but the import() "function" is probably what you wanted there.

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ) {
  import('../styles/globals-production.scss');
} else {
  import('../styles/globals-staging.scss');
}
```

Comment: An import declaration can only be used at the top level of a module.