# Next JS - How to apply Tailwind to specific pages

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I want to migrate an existing Next JS project to Tailwind CSS.

Is there a way to ensure Tailwind and Preflight/any default style only applies to specific pages? I basically need some pages to remain 100% untouched by Tailwind.

Things I've tried

- Modifying the content option in tailwind.config (that only affects the classes) and doesn't stop Tailwind applying base styling
- Applying global.css which has the Tailwind css conditionally (haven't been able to figure out how to do this)
- Disabling preflight. You can only do this for all pages or none of them

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same issue; so far I've found one solution that is more like a workaround than a solution.

**First step**

Install the [postcss-nested](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-nested) plugin for postcss and then create a CSS class to scope tailwind:

```
.tailwind-layout {
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
}
```

**Second step**

Create a react hook to use on the target pages:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useTailwindLayout() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const body = document.querySelector('body');
        body?.classList.add('tailwind-layout');
        return () => {
            body?.classList.remove('tailwind-layout');
        }
    }, []);
}
```

**Third step**

Use the hook on target pages components:

```
useTailwindLayout();
```

**Issue**

Tailwind show the following warning on console:

> (2:5) Nested @tailwind rules were detected, but are not supported.
> Consider using a prefix to scope Tailwind's classes:
> https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix

But so far, everything is working fine. I didn't find any issues or unexpected behavior. If I find a better solution, I'll update this answer.

Comment: in doc, it says to add tw- prefix have you tried adding it?

Comment: I'm going to post an answer that does this without `useEffect` which allows the styles to load correctly on the server side

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for **import tailwind css in specific component/file**.

**First step:**

Remove below tailwind css files from your global css.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**Second step:**

Now import tailwind css file like shown below in your component file (this will import all above three files automatically).

```
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
```

Cheers

Comment: This is not a good solution, because tailwind doesn't support nested rules and some classes don't work if you import tailwind like that and it also starts creating warnings in the console, this is a workaround with some relevant drawbacks

Comment: I don’t agree with this, because it doesn’t generate any warning in console and everything is working fine. I have tested this. 
Tailwind doesn’t support nested, so you can use sass there.

Comment: I just tested it and it generates the following warning:
(2:5) Nested @tailwind rules were detected, but are not supported. Consider using a prefix to scope Tailwind's classes: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix

Comment: And as you can see here https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8240 many other devs are having issues when they try to scope tailwind, so it's not working fine as you said

Answer (score 1):

This answer expounds upon [Gabriel Martins's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74608627/5013193) but does not require `useEffect` or directly manipulating the DOM. This is useful because then all your styles will be known server-side, rather than being loaded only on the front-end render. This is especially important if you're using "dark" styles. Without proper server-side styling, the user may see "flashes" of the white styling before the proper styles are loaded.

In `_document.tsx`:

```js
export default function Document(props: any) {
  const {
    shouldUseTailwind,
  } = props?.__NEXT_DATA__?.props?.pageProps;
  return (
    <Html>
      <body className={shouldUseTailwind ? 'tailwind' : ''}>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
};
```

In pages that you want to use tailwind:

```js
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      shouldUseTailwind: true,
    }
  }
}

export default function() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-100">
      Hello World
    </div>
  );
```

Now tailwind will only be loaded in pages where you return `shouldUseTailwind` in your `getServerSideProps`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was able to use tailwind only on 1 page by using `require()` in the page component, so that Tailwind is imported only when that page is active.

1. I removed global Tailwind import

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

2. I created separate .css file for Tailwind imports

```css
/* tailwind.css */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

3. In a specific page or component you can then call `require()` with the correct path to your CSS file that contains Tailwind imports. Note that the `require()` has to be inside the page/component definition.

```js
export default function Component() {
    ...
    require('./tailwind.css')
    ...
}
```

---

However if your `tailwind.css` file is still included after building the App, f.e. if you are statically serving the website, checkout the answer from **@JAM** instead that manages to solve this issue using `React.lazy` and `React.Suspense`: [conditional css in create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835825/conditional-css-in-create-react-app)

Answer (score -1):

This approach worked for me with Tailwind v3.

```css
/* Defining custom reusable Tailwind layers */
@layer tw-base {
  @tailwind base;
}
@layer tw-components {
  @tailwind components;
}
@layer tw-utilities {
  @tailwind utilities;
}

.my-scoped-class {
  /* Using custom layers */
  @layer tw-base, tw-components, tw-utilities;
}
```