# How to add tailwind css to specific pages only in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a style.css file that I have kept in the public folder which is basically the style sheet the HTML developer gave me along with the html files. Apart from that bootstrap is also being used in the project because the HTML pages use bootstrap here and there like for table, table-sortable and all. But I also have some component that I was given to add to my main nextjs project which consist tailwind css.

I followed the installation steps in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs) but it applies to all the pages and breaks the existing design. I also went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72577392/next-js-how-to-apply-tailwind-to-specific-pages) stackoverflow workaround but was not able to see any effect.

Another way was to specify the folder name in the tailwindcss.config file and also adding a prefix "tw-" but I was still not able to apply the changes.

Kindly guide me on how can I apply tailwindcss in particular pages and components without affecting the existing css and bootstrap class.

Comment: Did you add a prefix via the [prefix config option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix)? If you did this, you shouldn't have to specify a folder.

Comment: Yes did that too. But it broke the css of other pages.

Comment: You must update all your tailwind inline classes to use the prefix, e.g., `p-4` becomes `tw-p-4` on all your pages. If it breaks other pages by adding the prefix to the config, the other pages use TW styles. I'd prefix all of your TW styles, and when you are done migrating, use find & replace to remove all prefixes.